# "Mir ist nach etwas zumute" vs "Mir ist nach etwas"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I just said in conversation:

> Mir ist **nach** einem Nickerchen im Ruheraum **zumute**.

I wonder if it is just as acceptable to drop *zumute* without altering the meaning of the sentence? Or some nuance involved?

> {vs}: Mir ist **nach** einem Nickerchen im Ruheraum.

Answer (score 1):

It's acceptable.

But native speakers would rather leave out *im Ruheraum* when being sloppy, because it's a very stilted noun.

> Mir isnach'm Nickerchen zumute.
>
> Ich machmal'n Nickerchen.

Consider [other uses of »Ruheraum«.](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/innere-sicherheit-bundeskriminalamt-deutschland-kein-ruheraum-mehr-141245.html)

> Deutschland dient Terroristen vornehmlich als Ruheraum.